# Insert large JSON content into Oracle Database with JSON constraint

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I have below table

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_JSON_tbl" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "json_content" CLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT "TEST_JSON" CHECK (json_contentIS JSON) ENABLE
   )
```

Then i inserted a large JSON string whose length is larger that 4000. Really it is 15000 in length.
I tried with the below SQL by splitting the content into equal chunks.

```
insert into TEST_JSON_tbl (id,json_content)
  values
  (100,
      to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
    ...
    ||to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')
  );
```

I am getting below error

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST_JSON) violated
```

can anyone help to solve this issue

Comment: The error is simply saying that the inserted string is *not a valid JSON*.  Note also that your `CREATE TABLE` is invalid as you check a column `cclob`that is not defined in the table.

Comment: Also, your use of quotes in the table DDL may invalidate your insert, because your column names are not quoted there. Generally speaking once you define something with quotes, Oracle will require you to use quotes in all future references to the object in question. For best results, _never_ use quotes in your table DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across your question.

As @marmite-bomber already mentioned your test-insert doesn't work because there is no json in parameter passed to to_clob routine.

```
create table some_table(
  clob_col clob,
  constraint json_check check (clob_col is json) enable
);

insert into some_table values(to_clob(' <=4000 symbols ')); <-- failed. constraint violated
insert into some_table values(to_clob('{}')); <-- test passed with just an empty json-object for example
insert into some_table values(to_clob('{"key":"value","key1":"value2"}')); <-- test passed using a json-object with some data in it
```

And about the way table is defined. There is no need to use double-quotes

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_JSON_tbl
   (    ID NUMBER, 
    json_content CLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT TEST_JSON CHECK (json_content IS JSON) ENABLE
   )

insert into TEST_JSON_tbl(id,json_content) values (100, to_clob('{"key":"value","key1":"value2"}')) <-- works fine
```

Based on json example you gave below code is working fine

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_JSON_tbl
   (    ID NUMBER, 
    json_content CLOB, 
     CONSTRAINT TEST_JSON CHECK (json_content IS JSON) ENABLE
   )

declare 
  c clob := '{"key_0": "key_0", "key_1": "key_1", "key_2": "key_2", "key_3": "key_3", "key_4": "key_4", "key_5": "key_5", "key_6": "key_6", "key_7": "key_7", "key_8": "key_8", "key_9": "key_9", "key_10": "key_10", "key_11": "key_11", "key_12": "key_12", "key_13": "key_13", "key_14": "key_14", "key_15": "key_15", "key_16": "key_16", "key_17": "key_17", "key_18": "key_18", "key_19": "key_19", "key_20": "key_20", "key_21": "key_21", "key_22": "key_22", "key_23": "key_23", "key_24": "key_24", "key_25": "key_25", "key_26": "key_26", "key_27": "key_27", "key_28": "key_28", "key_29": "key_29", "key_30": "key_30", "key_31": "key_31", "key_32": "key_32", "key_33": "key_33", "key_34": "key_34", "key_35": "key_35", "key_36": "key_36", "key_37": "key_37", "key_38": "key_38", "key_39": "key_39", "key_40": "key_40", "key_41": "key_41", "key_42": "key_42", "key_43": "key_43", "key_44": "key_44", "key_45": "key_45", "key_46": "key_46", "key_47": "key_47", "key_48": "key_48", "key_49": "key_49", "key_50": "key_50", "key_51": "key_51", "key_52": "key_52", "key_53": "key_53", "key_54": "key_54", "key_55": "key_55", "key_56": "key_56", "key_57": "key_57", "key_58": "key_58", "key_59": "key_59", "key_60": "key_60", "key_61": "key_61", "key_62": "key_62", "key_63": "key_63", "key_64": "key_64", "key_65": "key_65", "key_66": "key_66", "key_67": "key_67", "key_68": "key_68", "key_69": "key_69", "key_70": "key_70", "key_71": "key_71", "key_72": "key_72", "key_73": "key_73", "key_74": "key_74", "key_75": "key_75", "key_76": "key_76", "key_77": "key_77", "key_78": "key_78", "key_79": "key_79", "key_80": "key_80", "key_81": "key_81", "key_82": "key_82", "key_83": "key_83", "key_84": "key_84", "key_85": "key_85", "key_86": "key_86", "key_87": "key_87", "key_88": "key_88", "key_89": "key_89", "key_90": "key_90", "key_91": "key_91", "key_92": "key_92", "key_93": "key_93", "key_94": "key_94", "key_95": "key_95", "key_96": "key_96", "key_97": "key_97", "key_98": "key_98", "key_99": "key_99", "key_100": "key_100", "key_101": "key_101", "key_102": "key_102", "key_103": "key_103", "key_104": "key_104", "key_105": "key_105", "key_106": "key_106", "key_107": "key_107", "key_108": "key_108", "key_109": "key_109", "key_110": "key_110", "key_111": "key_111", "key_112": "key_112", "key_113": "key_113", "key_114": "key_114", "key_115": "key_115", "key_116": "key_116", "key_117": "key_117", "key_118": "key_118", "key_119": "key_119", "key_120": "key_120", "key_121": "key_121", "key_122": "key_122", "key_123": "key_123", "key_124": "key_124", "key_125": "key_125", "key_126": "key_126", "key_127": "key_127", "key_128": "key_128", "key_129": "key_129", "key_130": "key_130", "key_131": "key_131", "key_132": "key_132", "key_133": "key_133", "key_134": "key_134", "key_135": "key_135", "key_136": "key_136", "key_137": "key_137", "key_138": "key_138", "key_139": "key_139", "key_140": "key_140", "key_141": "key_141", "key_142": "key_142", "key_143": "key_143", "key_144": "key_144", "key_145": "key_145", "key_146": "key_146", "key_147": "key_147", "key_148": "key_148", "key_149": "key_149", "key_150": "key_150", "key_151": "key_151", "key_152": "key_152", "key_153": "key_153", "key_154": "key_154", "key_155": "key_155", "key_156": "key_156", "key_157": "key_157", "key_158": "key_158", "key_159": "key_159", "key_160": "key_160", "key_161": "key_161", "key_162": "key_162", "key_163": "key_163", "key_164": "key_164", "key_165": "key_165", "key_166": "key_166", "key_167": "key_167", "key_168": "key_168", "key_169": "key_169", "key_170": "key_170", "key_171": "key_171", "key_172": "key_172", "key_173": "key_173", "key_174": "key_174", "key_175": "key_175", "key_176": "key_176", "key_177": "key_177", "key_178": "key_178", "key_179": "key_179", "key_180": "key_180", "key_181": "key_181", "key_182": "key_182", "key_183": "key_183", "key_184": "key_184", "key_185": "key_185", "key_186": "key_186", "key_187": "key_187", "key_188": "key_188", "key_189": "key_189", "key_190": "key_190", "key_191": "key_191", "key_192": "key_192", "key_193": "key_193", "key_194": "key_194", "key_195": "key_195", "key_196": "key_196", "key_197": "key_197", "key_198": "key_198", "key_199": "key_199", "key_200": "key_200", "key_201": "key_201", "key_202": "key_202", "key_203": "key_203", "key_204": "key_204", "key_205": "key_205", "key_206": "key_206", "key_207": "key_207", "key_208": "key_208", "key_209": "key_209", "key_210": "key_210", "key_211": "key_211", "key_212": "key_212", "key_213": "key_213", "key_214": "key_214", "key_215": "key_215", "key_216": "key_216", "key_217": "key_217", "key_218": "key_218", "key_219": "key_219", "key_220": "key_220", "key_221": "key_221", "key_222": "key_222", "key_223": "key_223", "key_224": "key_224", "key_225": "key_225", "key_226": "key_226", "key_227": "key_227", "key_228": "key_228", "key_229": "key_229", "key_230": "key_230", "key_231": "key_231", "key_232": "key_232", "key_233": "key_233", "key_234": "key_234", "key_235": "key_235", "key_236": "key_236", "key_237": "key_237", "key_238": "key_238", "key_239": "key_239", "key_240": "key_240", "key_241": "key_241", "key_242": "key_242", "key_243": "key_243", "key_244": "key_244", "key_245": "key_245", "key_246": "key_246", "key_247": "key_247", "key_248": "key_248", "key_249": "key_249", "key_250": "key_250", "key_251": "key_251", "key_252": "key_252", "key_253": "key_253", "key_254": "key_254", "key_255": "key_255", "key_256": "key_256", "key_257": "key_257", "key_258": "key_258", "key_259": "key_259", "key_260": "key_260", "key_261": "key_261", "key_262": "key_262", "key_263": "key_263", "key_264": "key_264", "key_265": "key_265", "key_266": "key_266", "key_267": "key_267", "key_268": "key_268", "key_269": "key_269", "key_270": "key_270", "key_271": "key_271", "key_272": "key_272", "key_273": "key_273", "key_274": "key_274", "key_275": "key_275", "key_276": "key_276", "key_277": "key_277", "key_278": "key_278", "key_279": "key_279", "key_280": "key_280", "key_281": "key_281", "key_282": "key_282", "key_283": "key_283", "key_284": "key_284", "key_285": "key_285", "key_286": "key_286", "key_287": "key_287", "key_288": "key_288", "key_289": "key_289", "key_290": "key_290", "key_291": "key_291", "key_292": "key_292", "key_293": "key_293", "key_294": "key_294", "key_295": "key_295", "key_296": "key_296", "key_297": "key_297", "key_298": "key_298", "key_299": "key_299", "key_300": "key_300", "key_301": "key_301", "key_302": "key_302", "key_303": "key_303", "key_304": "key_304", "key_305": "key_305", "key_306": "key_306", "key_307": "key_307", "key_308": "key_308", "key_309": "key_309", "key_310": "key_310", "key_311": "key_311", "key_312": "key_312", "key_313": "key_313", "key_314": "key_314", "key_315": "key_315", "key_316": "key_316", "key_317": "key_317", "key_318": "key_318", "key_319": "key_319", "key_320": "key_320", "key_321": "key_321", "key_322": "key_322", "key_323": "key_323", "key_324": "key_324", "key_325": "key_325", "key_326": "key_326", "key_327": "key_327", "key_328": "key_328", "key_329": "key_329", "key_330": "key_330", "key_331": "key_331", "key_332": "key_332", "key_333": "key_333", "key_334": "key_334", "key_335": "key_335", "key_336": "key_336", "key_337": "key_337", "key_338": "key_338", "key_339": "key_339", "key_340": "key_340", "key_341": "key_341", "key_342": "key_342", "key_343": "key_343", "key_344": "key_344", "key_345": "key_345", "key_346": "key_346", "key_347": "key_347", "key_348": "key_348", "key_349": "key_349", "key_350": "key_350", "key_351": "key_351", "key_352": "key_352", "key_353": "key_353", "key_354": "key_354", "key_355": "key_355", "key_356": "key_356", "key_357": "key_357", "key_358": "key_358", "key_359": "key_359", "key_360": "key_360", "key_361": "key_361", "key_362": "key_362", "key_363": "key_363", "key_364": "key_364", "key_365": "key_365", "key_366": "key_366", "key_367": "key_367", "key_368": "key_368", "key_369": "key_369", "key_370": "key_370", "key_371": "key_371", "key_372": "key_372", "key_373": "key_373", "key_374": "key_374", "key_375": "key_375", "key_376": "key_376", "key_377": "key_377", "key_378": "key_378", "key_379": "key_379", "key_380": "key_380", "key_381": "key_381", "key_382": "key_382", "key_383": "key_383", "key_384": "key_384", "key_385": "key_385", "key_386": "key_386", "key_387": "key_387", "key_388": "key_388", "key_389": "key_389", "key_390": "key_390", "key_391": "key_391", "key_392": "key_392", "key_393": "key_393", "key_394": "key_394", "key_395": "key_395", "key_396": "key_396", "key_397": "key_397", "key_398": "key_398", "key_399": "key_399", "key_400": "key_400", "key_401": "key_401", "key_402": "key_402", "key_403": "key_403", "key_404": "key_404", "key_405": "key_405", "key_406": "key_406", "key_407": "key_407", "key_408": "key_408", "key_409": "key_409", "key_410": "key_410", "key_411": "key_411", "key_412": "key_412", "key_413": "key_413", "key_414": "key_414", "key_415": "key_415", "key_416": "key_416", "key_417": "key_417", "key_418": "key_418", "key_419": "key_419", "key_420": "key_420", "key_421": "key_421", "key_422": "key_422", "key_423": "key_423", "key_424": "key_424", "key_425": "key_425", "key_426": "key_426", "key_427": "key_427", "key_428": "key_428", "key_429": "key_429", "key_430": "key_430", "key_431": "key_431", "key_432": "key_432", "key_433": "key_433", "key_434": "key_434", "key_435": "key_435", "key_436": "key_436", "key_437": "key_437", "key_438": "key_438", "key_439": "key_439", "key_440": "key_440", "key_441": "key_441", "key_442": "key_442", "key_443": "key_443", "key_444": "key_444", "key_445": "key_445", "key_446": "key_446", "key_447": "key_447", "key_448": "key_448", "key_449": "key_449", "key_450": "key_450", "key_451": "key_451", "key_452": "key_452", "key_453": "key_453", "key_454": "key_454", "key_455": "key_455", "key_456": "key_456", "key_457": "key_457", "key_458": "key_458", "key_459": "key_459", "key_460": "key_460", "key_461": "key_461", "key_462": "key_462", "key_463": "key_463", "key_464": "key_464", "key_465": "key_465", "key_466": "key_466", "key_467": "key_467", "key_468": "key_468", "key_469": "key_469", "key_470": "key_470", "key_471": "key_471", "key_472": "key_472", "key_473": "key_473", "key_474": "key_474", "key_475": "key_475", "key_476": "key_476", "key_477": "key_477", "key_478": "key_478", "key_479": "key_479", "key_480": "key_480", "key_481": "key_481", "key_482": "key_482", "key_483": "key_483", "key_484": "key_484", "key_485": "key_485", "key_486": "key_486", "key_487": "key_487", "key_488": "key_488", "key_489": "key_489", "key_490": "key_490", "key_491": "key_491", "key_492": "key_492", "key_493": "key_493", "key_494": "key_494", "key_495": "key_495", "key_496": "key_496", "key_497": "key_497", "key_498": "key_498", "key_499": "key_499"}';
begin
  insert into TEST_JSON_tbl(id, json_content) values(100, c);
  commit;
end;   

select * from TEST_JSON_tbl; <-- returns one row
```

Comment: Thanks, But I have JSON string whose length is more that 4000 characters

Comment: @ThangarajanPannerselvam just read the JSON into a clob variable and go ahead

declare 
  c clob := '{"key":"value","key1":"value2"}';
begin
  insert into some_table values(c);
end;

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thangarajan8/b3af217f103f9c29c70be23c38cb2681/raw/349efc8675bed120e296b2ee7b158e130c4b189a/json_content.json this is my JSON content